# Cleaning up nested re.sub statements 

Tags: python, regex, database

Can someone help me clean up this nested regex (re.sub) in python, please? I know there must be a better way to do this but I can't figure how.

```
re.sub('.*Chairman.*','Executive Director',re.sub('.*Managing Director.*','Executive Director',row['capacity']))
```

I have a column of strings (row['capacity']) that I've pulled from a database as part of a set and I want to iterate through it, replacing any lines that contain 'chairman' or 'managing director' with 'Executive director' when I write it to the set.

here's the full line of code:

```
wrhkset = set (( row['organization'], row['lastname'], row['givenname'], re.sub('.*Chairman.*','Executive Director',re.sub('.*Managing Director.*','Executive Director',row['capacity'])) ) for row in wrhk)
```

NOTE: 'wrhk' is a tuple of lists. I can include more of the code if necessary, but I'm really just hoping for a more streamlined way to tackle the nested `re.sub` statements I have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `|` to join two regexs with "or":

```
re.sub(r'''(?x)
     .*(
     Chairman | Managing[]Director     # or
     ).*     
     ''','Executive Director', row['capacity'])
```

Comment: -1 The regex is much better expressed as `.*(Chairman|Managing Director|another_title|etc).*` so that the trailing `.*` is done only once.

Comment: And you need `Managing[ ]Director`; in re.VERBOSE mode "Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash"

Answer (score -1):

Building on @ubuntu's response I used an OR operator & re.compile:

```
patterns = re.compile('(.*Chairman.*)|(.*Managing Director.*)|(.*Chief Executive.*)|(.*CEO.*)')
```

then:

```
wrhkset = set (( row['organization'], row['lastname'], row['givenname'], patterns.sub('Executive Director',row['capacity']) ) for row in wrhk)
```

This way I can keep adding patterns without turning my set line into an unreadable mess.

Thanks!

Comment: -1 You need only two each of `.*`, `(` and `)`: '.*(Chairman|Managing Director|Chief Executive|CEO).*'